# ¿Escribir dos puntos ":" antes de una fórmula matemática separada en un texto científico?

Tags: puntuación, matemáticas, ciencia

Es frecuente en los libros y textos científicos, al escribir matemáticas, el separar fórmulas para resaltarlas. Por ejemplo:

[image]

En todos los libros en inglés nunca escriben nada antes de dichas fórmulas. Mi profesor también me ha confirmado que no debo escribir dos puntos antes de las fórmulas, pero a mí no termina de gustarme como queda. En mi opinión queda mucho mejor así:

[image]

Así que la pregunta es simple: ¿cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: En la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq) no se especifica el uso de los dos puntos para nada parecido. Ambas versiones se ven bien.

Comment: Las fórmulas para mí funcionan casi como una locución nominal.  Por ejemplo, «Los *Cₙ* verifican **algo**».  Ese algo es la fórmula y como no diríamos «Los *Cₙ* verifican: **algo**», no usaría los dos puntos con la fórmula entera.  Escribirla en otro renglón es solo para legibilidad aunque fácilmente se podría ponerla dentro del renglón principal

Comment: Veo que esto se debatió en TEX (otro sitio de [SE]): [For formal articles, should a displayed equation be followed by a punctuation to conform to the language grammar ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7542). La respuesta es que no, citando el libro [Mathematical writing](http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf): _Don’t overdo the use of colons. While the colon in ‘Deﬁne it as follows:’ is ﬁne, the one in ‘We have: ⟨formula⟩’ should be omitted since the formula just completes the sentence. Some papers had more colons than periods._

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo con el comentario de @guifa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Ustanak cubre perfectamente lo dicho. Solamente como referencia, y para que no quede relegado entre los comentarios, indicaré que esto se debatió en [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) (otro sitio de [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)): [For formal articles, should a displayed equation be followed by a punctuation to conform to the language grammar?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7542/108315).

La respuesta es que no, citando el libro [*Mathematical Writing*](http://tex.loria.fr/typographie/mathwriting.pdf) de Donald E. Knuth, Tracy Larrabee y Paul M. Roberts:

> Don’t overdo the use of colons. While the colon in ‘Deﬁne it as
>   follows:’ is ﬁne, the one in ‘We have: ⟨formula⟩’ should be omitted
>   since the formula just completes the sentence. Some papers had more
>   colons than periods.

En general, este documento me está pareciendo interesantísimo. Su lectura no depara demasiadas sorpresas para quien haya tratado con textos matemáticos, pero es bonito ver la racionalización de la escritura para que sea lo más práctica posible. Uno podría objetar que este documento se refiere al inglés, pero yo contra-objeto con que la escritura científica –y sobre todo matemática– tiene un estilo estándar, independiente del idioma en que se escriba.

El resto de las respuestas en TeX ofrecen referencias muy válidas, incluyendo otra que enlaza con una tercera comunidad de Stack Exchange, [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), en la que bajo la pregunta [Periods and commas in mathematical writing](https://mathoverflow.net/q/6675) empieza el debate con algo un poco diferente a lo que estamos contestando aquí. En este caso, si tras la fórmula debería añadirse un signo de puntuación.

Sin embargo, la [primera respuesta](https://mathoverflow.net/a/6683) da una referencia que es a la que implícitamente ya llegamos aquí:

> > **Tautology 2.3.1** — A mathematical text is, before everything else, a text.
>
> from Michèle Audin's *Conseils aux auteurs de textes mathématiques*,
>   which you can get from her webpage.

Así que resumiendo: escribe la fórmula como si fuera un texto normal. Luego, hazla lucir.

Answer (score 3):

Cuando hacía mis documentos en LaTeX, solamente usaba ":" cuando iba a introducir un resultado final o bien, el inicio de un resultado.

Pero si se va a poner a cada rato, es porque se quiere enfatizar nada más.

No es algo que quite el sueño, pero de todas formas es cuestión de gustos. No produce hoyos en el lenguaje ni tampoco lo esquilma.

Comment: +1 Comparto la visión. Yo también soy matemático. Estuve repasando algún libro de la carrera y en ninguno de ellos se introducen las fórmulas con dos puntos. Eso sí, a veces las antecede una coma. Por ejemplo: `Con esta notación, <salto de línea> (an) = a0 + a1 + ... <salto de línea>`. Básicamente veo que se trabaja con la fórmula como si fuera un elemento más de la frase, pero que se separa con un salto de línea por claridad. Por tanto, si hubiera de llevar algún signo de puntuación antes, pues se le pone con normalidad.

Comment: @fedorqui Sí, si de hecho parece ser un criterio general, pero quería saber si había alguna norma específica al respecto. Pero bueno, tiene mucho sentido la explicación de que las  fórmulas, aunque estén separadas, forman parte de la misma frase y por tanto deben puntuarse de acuerdo a ésta.